# Diagonal lines over pcolor (facet edges don't match!)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If I use pcolor with a large enough grid, then the facet edges don't match the color squares. Here's an example:

```
>> pcolor(rand(18))
```

produces this image:

[image]

whereas

```
>> pcolor(rand(19))
```

produces this one:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Post your complete code. `pcolor(rand(19))` by itself works perfectly fine to me

Comment: @LuisMendo That's literaly it. I found the problem by trying to plot a 2-D histogram, and that code was obviously more complex, but while trying to isolate the problem I discovered that pcolor(rand(19)) on it's own from the matlab prompt is all it takes to produce that second plot. Perhaps it's an issue with my local MATLAB preferences somewhere?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you drawing the lines on top of the `pcolor` plot or is that just the result of `figure;pcolor(rand(19))` alone? What version of Matlab are you using? Maybe this is an OpenGL issue? What happens if you change the `'Renderer'` property: `set(gcf,'Renderer','painters')`? And do you need to to use `pcolor` at all as opposed to an `image` plot.

Comment: @horchler Good catch, yeah changing the renderer fixes the issue. The plots look fine using 'painters' or 'zbuffer', so I suspect that you are right and OpenGL is the issue. From www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html I have discovered that another solution is to use software OpenGL by typing `opengl software`. If you'd like to write your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, it appears that this may be a hardware-related OpenGL issue. One way to resolve this if it occurs is to change the `'Renderer'` property of the figure:

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','painters')
```

or

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer')
```

If OpenGL is necessary, you can try switching to a software-renderer via the [`opengl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) command:

```
opengl software
```

You might make sure that you have the latest drivers for your graphics card.